# Help regarding odd/even functions and limits.

Tags: limits, derivatives, proof-writing, proof-explanation

[image]

Hey I was wondering if I'm missing something in my proof or if there are any gaps of logic.. Specifically I'm not sure about my justification of the chain rule and overall accuracy..

**b.**

Claim: $g(x) = -g(-x)$ ($g$ is odd)

Proof:

$-g\left(-x\right)\ =\ f\left(-x\right)-f\left(x\right)\ =>g\left(-x\right)=f\left(x\right)-f\left(-x\right)$

Then we have

$g\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)-f\left(-x\right) = -g(-x)$

Therefore $g$ is odd.

Now we show there exists a point $x_{0} ∈ R $ such that $g'(x_{0}) = 0$.

Note that by the algebra of differentiable functions $g$ is differentiable.

By (3a) we know that since $g$ is odd, we have

$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(g\left(x\right)\right)=0 =>\:\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(g\left(x\right)\right)=-0 = 0$

Therefore by HW10 question (5b) we know that $g$ has an extreme point in $R$, we shall denote it $x_{0}$.

Since $g$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$, and $x_{0}$ is an extreme point of $g$, by Fermat's theorem we have
$g'(x_{0}) = 0$.

**c.**

Note that since $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$, and $g'$ is differetiable at $f(x_{0})$ by the chain rule we have

$g'\left(x_{0}\right)=f'\left(x_{0}\right)-\left(-f'\left(-x_{0}\right)\right)\ =f'\left(x_{0}\right)+f'\left(-x_{0}\right)=0$

$=>f'\left(x_{0}\right)+f'\left(-x_{0}\right)=0$

Which mean $f'\left(x_{0}\right)$ and $f'\left(-x_{0}\right)$ are additive inverses of each other.

Then either $f'\left(x_{0}\right)=f'\left(-x_{0}\right)=0$, in which case there exist $x_{1}∈R$ such that $f'\left(x_{1}\right)=0$.

or we have $f'\left(x_{0}\right)\cdot f'\left(-x_{0}\right)<0$, in which case by Darboux's theorem there exist a point $c∈R$ such that

$x_{0}<c<-x_{0}$ or $-x_{0}<c<x_{0}$ and $f'(c)=0$.

Therefore there must exist an $x_{1}∈R$ such that $f'\left(x_{1}\right)=0$.

Comment: Out of interest, how did you do part (b) ?

Comment: I showed g is an odd functions, and since lim x->∞ g(x) = 0, lim x->-∞ g(x) = -0=0 so we proved priviously that if lim x->+-∞ is the same, then there must be an extream point, thus the deriavte at that point has to be 0. :)

Comment: I see! As to your question, $f(x)$ doesn't have to be bounded, so no, $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ doesn't necessarily exist. Also, if there does not exist $x_1$ such that $f'(x_1) = 0,$ then $f(x)$ is strictly monotone, and so the property $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( f(x) - f(-x) \right)  = 0$ cannot possibly hold.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ is defined on all $\mathbb{R}$ and so is $g(x)$.

$g(-x)=f(-x)-f(x)=-g(x)$ thus $g(x)$ is an odd function so $g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$

This means that $g(x)$ is not increasing or decreasing on *all* $\mathbb{R}$. There is at least one point $x_0$ where $g'(x_0)=0$

$g'(x_0)=f'(x_0)+f'(-x_0)=0\to f'(x_0)=-f'(-x_0)$

As $f(x)$ is differentiable, $f'(x)$ is continuous and $f'(x)$ has opposite values at $x_0$ and $-x_0$, then for the IVT there exists at least one $x_1\in(-x_0,x_0)$ such that $f'(x_1)=0$

Comment: Wait isn't the deriviate g(x)=f(x)-f(-x) and not g(x)=f(x)+f(-x)?

Comment: @MathCuriouss $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$ derivative after chain rule is $$g'(x)=f'(x)-f'(-x)(-1)=f'(x)+f'(-x)$$

Answer (score 0):

If there is no such $x_1$ then $f'(x) >0$ for all $x$ or $f'(x) <0$ for all $x$. [This is because derivatives always have intermedite value property. See Darboux Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)]. Suppose $f'(x) >0$ for all $x$. Then $f$ is strictly incerasing. This implies that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$ both exist (possibly $\pm \infty$). However, $g(n)=f(n)-f(-n)\to 0$. So $f$ has the same limits at $\pm \infty$ and $f$ is strictly increasing. Do you see a contradiction? [The case when $f$ is strictly decreasing is handled by changing $f$ to $-f$].

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ doesn't have to be bounded, so no, $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ doesn't necessarily exist.

$$$$

I would approach proving $(c)$ as follows:

If there does not exist $x_1$ such that $f'(x_1) = 0,$ then this means that $f(x)$ is *strictly* monotone - i.e. either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. Suppose that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing (the proof for strictly decreasing is similar). Let $c \in \mathbb{R}.$

By the definition of strictly increasing, $f(x) > f(c+1) > f(c)$ for all $x > c+1$ and $f(x) < f(c)$ for all $x < c$.

Then $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) < f(c) < f(c+1) < \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) \\ \implies \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(f(x)-f(-x)\right) \geq f(c+1)-f(c) > 0.$

This contradicts the property: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( f(x) - f(-x) \right)  = 0$.